# How to plot the grouped data?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-visualization

I have the following dataframe, it is a subset of a 200 row with an 18 types of cars.

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Vnum': [1497, 1923, 1002, 1229, 1168, 1644, 2002, 1879, 1265, 1176, 1305, 1080],
       'name': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Honda Civic', 'Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4','Honda Civic','Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Toyota Corolla','Toyota Corolla','Honda Civic'],
       'Enum': [23, 9, 2, 45, 13, 4, 25, 11, 6, 14, 27, 8],
       'Syear': [2019, 2000, 2003, 2000, 2000, 2019, 1977, 2000, 2003, 2003, 2000, 2000],
      
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Vnum', 'name','Vnum','Syear'])

print (df)
```

I need your help to visualize the data.

I want a bar plot that car names come on the horizontal axis also one bar that show the number of each year. (I add an image)
Any other plot will work I just need to see the relation of car and year number.

I couldn't go anywhere from this code.

```
df_gg=df.groupby(['name','Syear']); df_gg.groups
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (efficient alternative) -

```
df.groupby(['name', 'Syear'])['Vnum'].count().unstack(level=-1).plot(kind = 'bar', rot = 0)
```

[image]

**Timings**

[@Mlang's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64844591/4098013) solution -

```
300 ms ± 59.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

This one -

```
53.1 ms ± 4.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks @Vivek Kalyanarangan for providing a more efficient solution!

Comment: Isn't the main advantage that it does not modify the df?

Answer (score 2):

You can transform the grouped DataFrame to a pivot table and plot it.

```
df = df.groupby(['name', 'Syear']).count().reset_index()

pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'name', columns = 'Syear', values = 'Vnum').plot(kind = 'bar', rot = 0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to add addition value.

```py
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
    df['name_year'] = df.name + ' ' + df.Syear.apply(str)
    
    traces = []
    for name_year in list(set(df.name_year)):
        trace = go.Bar(name=name_year, 
                x=df[df['name_year'] == name_year].name,
                y=df[df['name_year'] == name_year].Vnum,
                text=df[df['name_year'] == name_year].Syear,
                textposition='auto')
        traces.append(trace)
    
    fig = go.Figure(data=traces)
    fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
    fig.show()
```

[image]

UPDATED:
Fixed code

Comment: @Vivek Kalyanarangan,@mlang,@Savostyanov Konstantin  Thank you all for your interesting codes. I could plot my data with all the methods, However, because of having the data for thirty years the legend became too long, and the plot looks mmm not very handsome. Maybe the bar plot is not suitable for this project at all.